# How do I debug an application crash (unhandled win32 exception) in vscode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-c++, vscode-debugger

I have a running application that crashes with "An unhandled win32 exception occurred in ..." dialog.  This only contains full-fledged Visual Studio in the available debuggers list even though Visual Studio Code is installed.

I would rather use vscode as it is my main dev environment.

How can I add it to the "Choose Just-In-Time Debugger" window's "Available Debuggers" list?

---

Update:

I found where the setting exists in the registry, with an example of how to set WinDbg as the debugger instead of Visual Studio.
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/6084/windows-debuggers-part-1-a-windbg-tutorial#_Toc64133667
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/configuring-automatic-debugging

Remaining step is to determine how VS Code's debugger likes to be invoked.

(I'm still open to cleaner ways to do this, however.)

---

Update 2:

Nearest I can tell, this last step is the big deal breaker.

According to this feature request:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10979

It doesn't look like the team at Microsoft is interested in making that an option. :_(

Comment: Please tag your language.

Comment: Tags updated (language=C++)

Comment: Run the application in the VS code debugger to begin with.